# Removing text above slider of wordpress website

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have my site in word press[Here is my website link](http://realestate.bluecoresys.com/). There is text above slider, when i remove it , automatically slider is going to be disappears. Can anybody help ???

Code is as follow :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

 <div id="page-wrap">

    Front slider  
             <div id="front-slides">

            <div class="slides_container" >

                    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[cycloneslider id="115"]' ); ?>

                         </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: you use any plugin for slider. can i show your code

Comment: i think it is solved, i didnot see on site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Remove You text "Front slider", open your `style.css` file and
change the `margin-bottom: 9px;` to `margin-top: 60px;` for `#front-slides` that will fix it:

```
#front-slides {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 60px; /* the minimum margin is 60px you, if you change to 50px, your slider will go under the menu div.. & that would makes disappear :) */
}
```